# IE browser when trying to save and close a page,

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer

I have a function in my JSP file:

```
function saveAndClose()
{
    document.myForm.action=getContextPath()+'/MyController.do?method=save';
    document.myForm.submit();
    window.parent.document.location.reload();
}
```

When I test on Firefox, all is OK, but when I test on IE, nothing is saved!

The action isn't reached in IE!

When I comment this line:

```
window.parent.document.location.reload();
```

I reach the action, and my data are saved.

Really I don't know why!

Comment: Is there any error in developer console?

Comment: What's the need for `location.reload`? since you are submitting the page it will reload automatically. Then forward the page using server side.

Comment: I have a pop up (a separate div) which is displayed, when I click on save and close, I wanna get the parent page.

Comment: I assume popup windows consists of very few fields. If so, submit that data via ajax. Finally close the popup window and reload. And as well server part, are you sure your form data reaching the action class?

Comment: I IE, it isn't reaching the action !

Comment: ... There's no JavaScript function `getContextPath()`, and after you submit, doing a reload is pointless--you're no longer on the same page. Right now you're relying on pure luck/timing.